# Delete first post and show second in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question in PHP.

I am creating a website with posts but I can't make the PHP to show just the second post (without show the first).

My code is like this:

```
     <?php

                        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM projects");

                        $x = 1;
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                            $nome = $row['name'];
                            $conteudo = $row['description'];
                            $imagem = $row['image'];
                            $imagem2 = $row['image2'];

                        ?>

                    <?php static $count2 = 0; if ($count2 == "1") { break; } else { ?>



                        <div class="content justify" id="projects-<?php echo $x; ?>"  >
                            <?php echo $conteudo; ?>

                            <?php if(!empty($imagem2)) { ?>
                                <img class="hide-for-small" src="images/contebt/project/<?php echo $image2; ?>">
                            <?php }; ?>

                        </div>
                    <?php $count2++; } ?>

                        <?php $x++;}; ?>
```

With this code I can show just the first post, but I want to show just the second. Can anybody help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM projects LIMIT 1,1`

Comment: You should be able to find details on [the `WHERE` and `LIMIT` clauses](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) in any basic tutorial. Also, you really shouldn't mix PHP and HTML like that. You'll regret it when it comes time to find problems.

Comment: THANK YOU u_mulder. Worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with this code :

**PHP**

```
   <?php
   $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM projects");
   $x = 0;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       $nome = $row['name'];
       $conteudo = $row['description'];
       $imagem = $row['image'];
       $imagem2 = $row['image2'];
       if (!$x) {
          $x = 1;
          continue;
       }
   ?>
   <div class="content justify" id="projects-<?php echo $x; ?>"  >
       <?php echo $conteudo; ?>

       <?php if(!empty($imagem2)) { ?>
           <img class="hide-for-small" src="images/contebt/project/<?php echo $image2; ?>">
       <?php } ?>
   </div>
   <?php
       $x++;
       }
   ?>
```

**SQL**

But you should directly espace the first row directly in mysql usign either limit :

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM projects LIMIT 1, 1");
```

or where statement :

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM projects where id > 1");
```